# SIPP: how to get sipp rtpcheck results in background mode

Tags: background, sipp

I am running sipp v3.7.1 with the -bg switch (background mode) and implementing the rtpcheck feature.
Following termination of the sipp process I am able to get the SIP result by grep-ing the screen log file but the screen log reports zero RTP packets. This is despite the fact that the rtpcheck debug file shows recieved packets and the check is successful. Tcpdump also shows recieved packets.

From screen log
*0 Total RTP pckts sent                  0.000 last period RTP rate (kB/s)*

So, I am trying to find a way to ascertain if the RTP check is successful. ( I can't use the rtpcheck_debug file as the file name is not customisable and the specific call is not identifiable)
Ideally, accessing the exit code would be the way to go but this seems to be unavailable in background mode. (Background mode is necessary for my use case).
Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried running in foreground. I can see the screenlog shows recieved audio stata whilst running but the final screen shows zero packets as above.